# Grails GORM loading collection of objects issue

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to load a list of Evaluations in a class named Contributor but I'm missing something as I cannot get my test passing.

My test is creating and saving objects as expected because when I do Evaluations.list() and Contributor.list() and print the values I see the data I saved.

Furthermore, when I select an Evaluation and print the value of its 'contributor' property it appears to be correct.

However, when I select a Contributor and print the values of its 'evaluations' property it is null.

I assume my mapping is the problem?

```
class Contributor {
    String name

    static hasMany = [evals:Evaluation]

    static mapping = {
        id column: 'user_id'
        evals joinTable:[name:'evaluation', column:'eval_id', key:'eval_user_id']
        version false
    }
}

class Evaluation {
    Contributor contributor
    String comment

    static mapping = {
        id column:'eval_id'
        contributor column:'eval_user_id'
        version false
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't assign `evals` like `contributor.evals = [eval]`. Rather invoke a dynamic method `addTo*()`: `contributor.addToEvals(eval)`. This will create a Hibernate collection for `evals` which will be persisted later.

The first one didn't work because Grails doesn't assign other end of association when you assign `eval.contributor`, i.e. it doesn't call `contributor.addToEvals(eval)`. I have no idea why - there must be some implementation reason.

So `contributor` remains with the same empty `evals` in Hibernate cache. If it falls out of cache and you re-read it, it will have `evals` filled, because the association is mapped only on `Eval` table's foreign key.

Empty `evals` are null - it's another Hibernate feature: when a collection is empty, it can be null. Just know it.

Here's an good short post explaining some Hibernate internals: http://blog.xebia.com/2008/03/advanced-hibernate-proxy-pitfalls/

Answer (score 0):

Ahh I've sussed it. The problem is the way I was saving the objects.

The following does not work:

```
def contributor = new Contributor([name:'Homer']).save(failOnError:true)
def eval = new Evaluation([contributor:contributor, comment:'Must read article']).save(failOnError:true)
```

This

```
def contributor = new Contributor([name:'Homer']).save(failOnError:true)
def eval = new Evaluation([contributor:contributor, comment:'a comment']).save(failOnError:true)
contributor.evals = [eval]
contributor.save(failOnError:true)
```

Or this, does work:

```
def contributor = new Contributor([name:'Homer'])
def eval = new Evaluation([contributor:contributor, comment:'a comment'])
contributor.evals = [eval]
contributor.save(failOnError:true)
```

Not sure I fully understand why the top save method doesn't work when selecting data since the id of the contributor is saved on the evaluation.